# Using sqlite database and it force closes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Class used to create database:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class sqlite extends Activity {
    public void sqlitetry(final SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDB) {
        String  createSql = "CREATE TABLE" +
                "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "name text not null);";
        sqLiteDB.execSQL(createSql);
    }

    public void sqlinit() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDatabase",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE id note exist MyTable(username Varchar, password Varchar PRIMARY KEY);");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from MyTable", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(c.isAfterLast() == false) {

        }       
    }
}
```

When I add this code to my login and registration confirmation class and start the activity, it force closes:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    sqlite as = new sqlite();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDB = null;
    as.sqlitetry(sqLiteDB);
    as.sqlinit();
```

After installing the apk on my device, this is shown in the logcat:

```
07-18 09:51:39.875: D/AndroidRuntime(25677): Shutting down VM
07-18 09:51:39.875: W/dalvikvm(25677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login1/com.example.login1.Login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.example.login1.sqlite.sqlitetry(sqlite.java:12)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.example.login1.Login.onCreate(Login.java:25)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    ... 11 more
```

I need to put the information of the user upon registration in the database and pull it out in order for the user to log in but it force closes and I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exception have You observed in logcat?

Comment: Your sqlite class extends `Activity`. Also you do not have `onCreate` method.

Comment: there you go. i forgot to post the Logcat. just finished editing. thanks!

Comment: @KarlCaday show us `SQLiteDatabase` class

Comment: i dont have SQLiteDatabase class.. as you can see I called it on my init class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sqlite` class extends Activity. Also you do not have `onCreate` method in sqlite

Then you have this

```
 sqlite as = new sqlite();
```

You need to start an activity using `startActivity(new Intent(myintent))`.

Suggest you study activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Also you have this

```
 sqlite as = new sqlite(); //sqlite class extends activity
 SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDB = null; // null value
 as.sqlitetry(sqLiteDB);
 as.sqlinit();
```

Your sqlite need not extend `Activity` if its just a helper class.

Also check this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Check out the tutorial @ Youtube By travis

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEg9OdufXmM (series 112 to 119 i guess)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the logcat, you can see that this line report the actual error:

```
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Following that line, you will see 2 line that is the stack of code execution that generate the actual error:

```
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.example.login1.sqlite.sqlitetry(sqlite.java:12)
07-18 09:51:39.882: E/AndroidRuntime(25677):    at com.example.login1.Login.onCreate(Login.java:25)
```

Based on this, your problem was simply becuase of null value `sqLiteDB`:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDB = null;
as.sqlitetry(sqLiteDB);
```

Comment: what should i do abt it?

Comment: call your init before your try.  init tends to come first, no?